# Custom Post Type for displaying products in a database table

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a WordPress project that I'm using as a CMS.  <strike>I also have a database with some products in it that I'd like to display on the site (gallery or portfolio maybe?)</strike> I have a custom post type for Products that I want to be editable in the wordpress admin (along with the rest of the content).

<strike>I know I have to do a custom post type (which I'm reading up on, probably will use Simple Fields plugin) but I'm not seeing a way to pull these values from a database.</strike>  Products will have ProductName, URL, Category, and Type.  I would want to list and add/edit/delete these in the word press admin side of course.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you all!

EDIT: I've created the Custom Post Type for `Products`.  Now each `Product` can have a `Category`, `Subcategory`, and `Type`, which I'm assuming will also need their own Custom Post Type if they are to be manageable right?

The layout for the products will be roughly: `ProductName`, `Type`, `Category`, `SubCategory`, `Document Name`, `Document URL`.  Remember the `Category`, `SubCategory`, `Type` will need to be manageable and editable so I guess they will need to be custom post types as well.

Thinking about this some more, could I use the built-in categories for MY custom post type categories and have the subcategories as children of the main categories? That might be the easier way out on that end.  But how would I map a custom post type of `ProductType` to my custom post type of `Product`?

Here is my product custom post type:

```
    /*  CUSTOM POST TYPE AREA FOR PRODUCTS   */
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_post_type' );

function create_product_post_type() 
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Products', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'products'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Product'),
        'new_item' => __('New Product'),
        'view_item' => __('View Product'),
        'search_item' => __('Search Products'),
        'not_found' => __('No products found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Products'           
        );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Products'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/functions/images/product.png',
        'hierarchial' => false,
            //'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "events" ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true

        );

        register_post_type( 'tf_events', $args);    
}
```

Comment: @drpcken - It would help if you can give a few examples of your data as well as the schema of your existing database *(is it in MySQL?)*

Comment: Yes Mike it will be in MySQL.  The exact fields are Category, SubCategory, Type (these will all be taxonomies right?), Product, PDF Name, and a URL.

Comment: To add... I'm building the custom post type now. I think I've got that part down.  I'm just curious how to add, edit, update from the db. Thanks!

Comment: If you already have a table in your database containing your products, you can't just have wordpress magically manage this data. a custom post type stores data in wordpress' tables, using its own structure. you can manage external data with wordpress, but you need to write all of the logic yourself- create, save, update, delete, etc.. Now perhaps I misunderstand what you've got here...

Comment: Thanks Milo, I have no problem letting WordPress manage the data in the database if that's the easier route.

Comment: It would certainly be easier, however, it requires you migrate your data over to custom posts.

Now that you've created your Product custom post type, when you log in to the dashboard, you'll see the tab "Products". This is where you'll create and edit each item.

Your product category and subcategory can be a single hierarchical [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). Product Type can be an additional taxonomy.

Any additional data you wish to store with each product can be entered into a [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: Ahh so that is what taxonomy is. I will use those instead of the default wordpress categories.  I went to add a new product, but it looks just like a post. I'd really like to remove the large Post box (I just want the product name), the exerpts, and especially the discussions and sidebar meta boxes (that is what they are called right?). If I create custom fields (such as DocumentURL), how can I get it as a field on the Add New Product page? Thank you!!

Comment: To remove the main content field and show custom fields, change the 'supports' argument in your `create_product_post_type` function to remove 'editor' and add 'custom-fields':

`'supports' => array('title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),`

Comment: That did it thanks!!  But when I add `custom-fields` it seems I have to add the custom fields on the fly when I'm creating the custom post type (product).  Can I pre-determine my custom fields (only 2 of them) and have meta boxes for them when creating a new product?

Comment: yes, with the [add meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function.

Comment: Thank you Milo, if you can make you second comment an answer I will gladly accept.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need to do is create [Custom Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies) for your products instead of second custom post type. You can create taxonomies that are hierarchical like categories, or non-hierachical like tags. Give them names, slugs, etc.

This way you won't interfere with the blog categories and tags, and get a more customized result.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to have a relationship between two different post types. In that case something like [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) will be required to "link up" the different post types.

Once you have the ability to perform these links, simply create custom entry boxes for your `Product` and `ProductType` post types.

As Milo mentioned above, you can remove `'editor'` from the custom post types.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I think I'm going to use ProductType as a taxonomy instead of having to create a new post type (makes sense right?).  I will take your advice though when I need to relate Posts.  Thanks!!